# How can I control coherence between error bar plots in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, errorbar

I have this data:

```
import pandas as pd
URL = "https://stepik.org/media/attachments/lesson/9250/atherosclerosis.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(URL)
atherosclerosis = data.groupby(["age", "dose"]).agg(['mean', 'std'])
atherosclerosis.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in atherosclerosis.columns]
atherosclerosis
```

Result:

```
          expr_mean  expr_std
age dose                      
1   D1    104.758464  5.863454
    D2    105.545864  4.369024
2   D1    101.004805  5.116310
    D2    102.273629  5.135374
```

And I plot error bars like this:

```
plot_data1 = atherosclerosis.xs('D1', level=1, drop_level=False)
plot_data2 = atherosclerosis.xs('D2', level=1, drop_level=False)
plot_index1 = [str(idx) for idx in plot_data1.index]
plot_index2 = [str(idx) for idx in plot_data2.index]
plt.errorbar(plot_index1, plot_data1["expr_mean"], 
             yerr=plot_data1["expr_std"]/2,
             marker="s", mfc='green', 
             markeredgewidth=2, capsize=4, capthick=2, 
             fmt='o-', ecolor="magenta")
plt.errorbar(plot_index2, plot_data2["expr_mean"], 
             yerr=plot_data2["expr_std"]/2,
             marker="s", mfc='green', 
             markeredgewidth=2, capsize=4, capthick=2, 
             fmt='o-', ecolor="magenta")
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: [Result]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wpaM.png)

Can I somehow connect (1, 'D1') with (1, 'D2') and (2, 'D1') with (2, 'D2'). Like this:

[image: [Like there]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI8BH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your plot data:

```
plot_data1 = atherosclerosis.xs(1, level=0, drop_level=False)
plot_data2 = atherosclerosis.xs(2, level=0, drop_level=False)
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Update:** to get what you are asking for, I would sort the data, and plot it against the range:

atherosclerosis = atherosclerosis.sort_index(level=(1,0))
atherosclerosis['range'] = np.arange(len(atherosclerosis))

```
plot_data1 = atherosclerosis.xs(1, level=0, drop_level=False)
plot_data2 = atherosclerosis.xs(2, level=0, drop_level=False)
plot_index1 = [str(idx) for idx in plot_data1.index]
plot_index2 = [str(idx) for idx in plot_data2.index]

# atherosclerosis.expr_mean.sort_index(level=['dose','age']).plot(alpha=0)
plt.errorbar(plot_data1['range'], plot_data1["expr_mean"], 
             yerr=plot_data1["expr_std"]/2,
             marker="s", mfc='green', 
             markeredgewidth=2, capsize=4, capthick=2, 
             fmt='o-', ecolor="magenta")
plt.errorbar(plot_data2['range'], plot_data2["expr_mean"], 
             yerr=plot_data2["expr_std"]/2,
             marker="s", mfc='green', 
             markeredgewidth=2, capsize=4, capthick=2, 
             fmt='o-', ecolor="magenta")

plt.xticks(atherosclerosis['range'], atherosclerosis.index);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do you know the way to make it look more like in example? For example, put (1, 'D1') and (2, 'D1') in one side and (1, 'D2'), (2, 'D2') in another. Maybe it possible in some other libraries (seasborn, plotly).

Comment: Thank you again. Exactly what i needed.